# grep regex solution for finding 3 or more dashes in a string

Tags: python, regex, bash, grep

I'm trying to build a bash script that will look for the keychain folder on a mac and delete it when found using grep. The challenging part is no 2 folders are alike. An example is C0955E7D-DCA1-542B-B506-72A054DET9FA. They all contain 3 or more dashes in the name. Not sure how to grep for this using regex. While in my "~/Library/Keychain/ directory, I was thinking something like...

```
ls | grep "*-*-*-*"
```

I was thinking that * would be wildcard and look for any amount of digits that will contain at-least 3 dashes between them.

I'm also opening to using python too (since it comes preinstalled on macs) but that seemed too complicated.

Comment: IMHO you could try to execute commands which you think of and edit your post with results about them.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide sample input, expected result, and your current result

Comment: Grep is filtering standard input or the lines of a file you provide as the input. What's your input? You seem to be looking for directories. Did you mean to use `find`, perhaps?

Comment: Also, you're mixing up shell patterns (where `*` is "zero or more of any character") and regular expressions (what grep uses - where `*` is a quantifier for the preceding character).

Comment: you are confusing [shell globs vs regular expressions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)... see if `ls *-*-*-*` gives the files you want to delete and then use `rm` instead of `ls` to delete them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will print all directory names with 3 or more dashes

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '[ $(echo {} | grep -o - | wc -l) -ge 3 ]' \; -print
```

Comment: This prints the folder and and the contents of each inside. Is there a way to get just the folder name? This way, my script will get the folder name and delete it.

Comment: Still lists multiple items but it is closer. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: np, to stop after finding the first item you can add -quit (after -print)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `(\w+-){3,}\w+`

**Explanation**:

`\w+` : word characters 1 or more times
`-` : hyphen
`(\w+-){3,}` : some word characters followed by hyphen 3 or more times
`\w+` : word characters 1 or more times

Comment: @Andreas OP mentioned `3 or more dashes in the name`

Answer (score 0):

grep ".+-.+-.+-.+" would be more accurate in your case.

```
. = any character
+ = one or more times (matches any character, one or more times)
(* = zero or more times)
```